# v-model with nested objects, accidentally reactivelly changing half array instead of single item

Tags: vue.js

It is supposed to dynamically add players, when u click 'add'. But it doesn't let you properly enter names. It changes the name for half the players in array.

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="player in players">
        <select v-model="player.type">
            <option :value="option" v-for="option in playerOptions">{{option.color}}</option>
        </select>
        <input v-if="player.type" type="text" v-model="player.type.name">
        <hr>
    </div>
    <button @click="addSel()">add select</button>
    <hr>
    {{players}}
</div>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: () => ({
            playerOptions: [{ color: 'red', name: ''},
                            { color: 'blue', name: ''}],
            players: [{ type: null }]
        }),
        methods: {
            addSel() {
                this.players.push({type: null})
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/origami1024/pen/ZEEMPQK

Comment: Always use keys with v-for, else in many cases you'll have apparent bugs during the array update. I'm not *sure* it's the reason why you have your bug, but by experience I'd guess there is a 90% probability it's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning an object as `player.type` in your options.

replace `option` with `option.color` (or some other non-object key) and it will work

TL;RD;

instead of

```html
<select v-model="player.type">
  <option :value="option" v-for="option in playerOptions">{{option.color}}</option>
</select>
```

use

```html
<select v-model="player.type">
  <option :value="option.color" v-for="option in playerOptions">{{option.color}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that destructuring works, but then selected value in selects goes blank, is there any quick way around it?

Comment: Not really, you would have to re-implement the `v-model` functionality. Anyway, it's bad design, you should be using proper keys.